# Can you make a VC++ Solution set preprocessor #defines on loaded projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, build-process

I have a library which supports a #define to control how it's built. However the library can be used by multiple EXE projects which want different versions. Can I make the app/EXE project set the #define to be used by the library when built, or set it in the solution?

The only other option I can think of is creating a separate build-configuration on the library project but that would quickly get out of control. That's common for e.g unicode/non-unicode builds but then you'd end up multiplying the number of configurations for every combination.

Comment: use a `config.h` file which sets the required preprocessor defines, which is included by the library project, but supplied by the application projects (drawback: you cant have more than 1 application project per solution file)

Comment: Isn't this the same as what librik suggests?

Comment: yes, indeed.. just noticed that answer (although my comment was written 5hours later ..strange).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following approach assumes that every .EXE/app (which uses this library) has its own Visual Studio Solution.

You do have control over the library, right?  Steps 1-3 will make changes to its project file, and step 4 adds a file to the library source code.

1. Set Project Properties > C/C++ > Advanced > Force Includes to `mylibrary_solution_defines.h` .
2. Edit Project Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories to put `$(SolutionDir);` at the beginning of the list of directories.
3. Set both Project Properties > General > Output Directory and Intermediate Directory to something relative to the solution directory.  Perhaps `$(SolutionDir)$(ProjectName)\$(Configuration)`?  You want to make sure the library gets rebuilt for every solution that uses it; there shouldn't be any sharing of .lib or .obj files.
4. Create an empty, dummy header file called `mylibrary_solution_defines.h` and put it in your library source code so a `#include "mylibrary_solution_defines.h"` will never fail.
5. In every app/EXE solution -- assuming you have different solutions for each app that uses this library, otherwise this whole plan will fail -- create a `mylibrary_solution_defines.h` file with your #defines in it.

Do you see what's happening?  Every library source file implicitly `#include`s `"mylibrary_solution_defines.h"`, and it preferentially gets that file from the solution directory.  So that file can be different for every solution.  So if your solution `ConsoleModeInterfaceProgram.sln` needs the library built with `#define TEXTONLY 1`, put that line into the `mylibrary_solution_defines.h` that's in the same directory as `ConsoleModeInterfaceProgram.sln`.

Comment: Thanks, have been looking for a solution to this for a while

Comment: aren't the two headers of step 4 and step 5 "fighting" each other? why do i need to put a dummy?

Comment: You put $(SolutionDir) first on the list in step 2, so that its header file will be used *if it is there*.  If there is no special header file in SolutionDir, then the empty one (step 4) is used, and does nothing.  This allows your library project to be used in all solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need separate build configurations for each library version that any of your applications requires. That's how the build system is designed.

The only way out would be to add the source code for the 'library' directly to the respective application projects and set the correct preprocessor settings per-project - this way, you still have the benefit of a shared codebase.

Comment: That's horrible :(. For N such settings you have 2^N build-configs. I hoped I could make a project inject a setting to a dependency or use a pre-build setting, or there was some solution-level settings. Oh well.