# Preprocessor definition / defined symbol, depending on (or inherited from) solution instead of project?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, project, c-preprocessor, symbols, solution

In vs2008's project settings you can define custom symbols, such as DEBUG or WIN32.

The thing is: I am using one project (a static library) in different solutions, and I'd like to build the same vcproj with a different predefined symbol in each solution.

Is there some way to define a 'solution-wide symbol'? Or can I somehow have a project inherit preprocessor defines from solution level or anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions don't have user-settable properties quite like that.  But it is possible to get the effect you want, as was explained in the answers to this previous StackOverflow question on the same topic, ["Can you make a VC++ Solution set preprocessor #defines on loaded projects?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272556/can-you-make-a-vc-solution-set-preprocessor-defines-on-loaded-projects)

Comment: Thanks, didn't find that solution before, but looks like a smart workaround.